# sp-pnp-js gives error when building TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, pnpjs

I've been asked to make changes to a TypeScript project and compile it to get a new JavaScript file. The JavaScript file is just to be referenced from a SharePoint site, so there's no SPFx involved here.

I downloaded the project from our TFS and did an "npm install" to get the node modules and that worked fine.

When I try to build it using "npm run-script build" I get a bunch of errors regarding sp-pnp-js. According to package.json, this is the version referenced:

```
"sp-pnp-js": "^2.0.5"
```

See the errors below. I'm completely at a loss here and I don't understand the errors. I know that the code is okay, so this is something wrong in my dev environment. What am I missing? Please help.

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/sp-pnp-js/lib/sharepoint/attachmentfiles.d.ts:71:5
    TS2416: Property 'delete' in type 'AttachmentFile' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'QueryableInstance'.
  Type '(eTag?: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(deleteOptions?: FetchOptions, parser?: ODataParser<any>) => Promise<any>'.
    Types of parameters 'eTag' and 'deleteOptions' are incompatible.
      Type 'FetchOptions' is not assignable to type 'string'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/sp-pnp-js/lib/sharepoint/files.d.ts:114:5
    TS2416: Property 'delete' in type 'File' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'QueryableShareableFile'.
  Type '(eTag?: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(deleteOptions?: FetchOptions, parser?: ODataParser<any>) => Promise<any>'.
    Types of parameters 'eTag' and 'deleteOptions' are incompatible.
      Type 'FetchOptions' is not assignable to type 'string'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/sp-pnp-js/lib/sharepoint/files.d.ts:286:5
    TS2416: Property 'delete' in type 'Version' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'QueryableInstance'.
  Type '(eTag?: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(deleteOptions?: FetchOptions, parser?: ODataParser<any>) => Promise<any>'.
    Types of parameters 'eTag' and 'deleteOptions' are incompatible.
      Type 'FetchOptions' is not assignable to type 'string'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/sp-pnp-js/lib/sharepoint/folders.d.ts:81:5
    TS2416: Property 'delete' in type 'Folder' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'QueryableShareableFolder'.
  Type '(eTag?: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(deleteOptions?: FetchOptions, parser?: ODataParser<any>) => Promise<any>'.
    Types of parameters 'eTag' and 'deleteOptions' are incompatible.
      Type 'FetchOptions' is not assignable to type 'string'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/sp-pnp-js/lib/sharepoint/items.d.ts:112:5
    TS2416: Property 'delete' in type 'Item' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'QueryableShareableItem'.
  Type '(eTag?: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(deleteOptions?: FetchOptions, parser?: ODataParser<any>) => Promise<any>'.
    Types of parameters 'eTag' and 'deleteOptions' are incompatible.
      Type 'FetchOptions' is not assignable to type 'string'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/sp-pnp-js/lib/sharepoint/lists.d.ts:151:5
    TS2416: Property 'delete' in type 'List' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'QueryableSecurable'.
  Type '(eTag?: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(deleteOptions?: FetchOptions, parser?: ODataParser<any>) => Promise<any>'.
    Types of parameters 'eTag' and 'deleteOptions' are incompatible.
      Type 'FetchOptions' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: No takers? I still have this issue. I anyone has a clue, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got this working. I deleted the node modules and run `npm install` to retrieve the modules according to package.json. I did try that several times before still getting the same error, but this time I added this command:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript
```

I'm pretty sure I did that too at some point before, but this time everything started working. Maybe typescript didn't install properly the first time.

Anyway, my issue is solved but I leave my question and answer to anyone having the same issue.